# UIManager.getDefaults().put() doesn´t work with colors

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a GUI with a JTabbedPane, and I want to change its Layout. I tried to do this with the UIManager:

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("TabbedPane.foreground",Color.BLACK);
```

However, the color does not change, but when I change for example the border insets

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("TabbedPane.contentBorderInsets", new Insets(0,0,0,0));
```

it works, but everything which needs a color doesn´t work!

The LAF from my GUI is `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`

Comment: What part of the tabbed pane are you expecting to change color?

Comment: Thats an example: in general i can´t change color

Comment: Setting the `foreground` property works fine for me using JDK8 on Windows 7. So again, What part of the tabbed pane to you expect to change color??? Post [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.