# UIManager doesn´t work with colors

Tags: java

favorite

I have a GUI with a JTabbedPane, and I want to change its Layout. I tried to do this with the UIManager:

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("TabbedPane.foreground",Color.BLACK);
```

However, the color does not change, but when I change for example the border insets

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("TabbedPane.contentBorderInsets", new Insets(0,0,0,0));
```

it works, but everything which needs a color doesn´t work!

The LAF from my GUI is `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP asked the exact same question an hour before this one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40703379/243373).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JTabbedPane.setForegroundAt():

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setForegroundAt(int,%20java.awt.Color)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I dont know how i use your link to solve my problem